# How do I resolve a 'Symfony\RfcComplianceException: Email "" does not comply with addr-spec of RFC 2822' when running a phpunit test in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I ran the test suite that comes with Laravel and one of the tests in the RegistrationTest fails with this error message:

> The following exception occurred during the last request:  Symfony\Component\Mime\Exception\RfcComplianceException: Email "" does not comply with addr-spec of RFC 2822. in C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\symfony\mime\Address.php:54.

Sending emails work normally as do registering users despite this test failing.

What can I do to resolve this so that the test passes?

This is the code for the failing test:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Laravel\Fortify\Features;
use Laravel\Jetstream\Jetstream;
use Tests\TestCase;

class RegistrationTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;
   
    public function test_new_users_can_register()
    {
        if (! Features::enabled(Features::registration())) {
            return $this->markTestSkipped('Registration support is not enabled.');
        }

        $response = $this->post('/register', [
            'first_name' => 'TestFNAME',
            'last_name' => 'TestLNAME',
            'email' => 'test@example.com',
            'mobile_phone_number' => '08011223344',
            'password' => 'password',
            'password_confirmation' => 'password',
            'terms' => Jetstream::hasTermsAndPrivacyPolicyFeature(),
        ]);
        $this->assertAuthenticated();
        $response->assertRedirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
    }
}
```

This is a snippet of the code I use for validating user registration inputs:

```
Validator::make($input, [
   'first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
   'last_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
   'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
   'mobile_phone_number' => ['required', 'string', 'min:11', 'max:15', 'unique:users', 'phone:NG,mobile'],
   'password' => $this->passwordRules(),
   'terms' => Jetstream::hasTermsAndPrivacyPolicyFeature() ? ['required', 'accepted'] : '',
        ])->validate();
```

Comment: Could you add the code you're using for validating your input? It seems like the `email` field is getting lost through the process so trying to figure out exactly where  may help you. it's hard to tell you what's wrong without additional context of your actual code-base

Comment: Please can you share the controller method that is responding to this `POST /register` route? Is it Jetstream or some custom code you've written?

Comment: Hi, @simonhamp, I'm using Jetstream. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply... did you manage to resolve the issue?

Comment: No, I'm yet to resolve the issue as I  haven't given testing attention for some time.